# Parser Google Search results

Tags: xml, json, parsing, search

Is there any way to parse Google search's results or retrieve them on an XML or JSON? I tried with Google's API but I didn't find a solution! 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The official API from Google is Google Custom Search. Find more details [here](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview)

Comment: But I need the result directly in XML or JSON because I'll use it for an app written in Objective-C

Comment: Look here: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/using_rest it explains how to use REST to obtain JSON results

Comment: Google has some limitations on the JSON API but I found there is an XML API that you can seemingly use freely if you have paid for Google Site Search:

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results